# Cannot to sign in with graphic mode

Tags: 15.04, lubuntu, login

I had been using lubuntu 15.04. Yesterday, I tried to change a name of my PC. Since then, when I try to switch on my pc, I see only the loading screen, but the login window doesn't show.

I changed the name in /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname. I tried to find broken packages in recovery mode, but it still doesn't work.

I have here a lot of my work and system setting. Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you log in through TTY  ( that's Ctrl+Alt+F2 )  ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
The problem escalated to the low-graphic mode. Now, when I switch on my PC, after Lubuntu loading appears the message with warning: "The system is running in low-graphics mode".

Is there any possibility, how to reinstall the Lubuntu without any loss of my personal data and installed packages (programs)? Thanks.